# I can't figure out how to get this script to print a list of infected files to an output file

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, directory

I have this antivirus assignment to find a specific virus `SigData = Infected`. I am lost on how to finish this script to get it to print a list of infected files to an output file.

I tried `os.listdir(path)`, but it says the path is not defined. I don't know how else to print the list I need from this code:

```
import os
import inspect
SigData="Infected"


def search(path): #Searches for files in path.
    filestodisinfect = []
    filelist = os.listdir(path)
    for filename in filelist:
        if os.path.isdir(path+"/"+filename): #Looks for folder
            filestodisinfect.extend(search(path+"/"+filename))
        elif filename[-3:] == ".py": #Searches for python scripts to disinfect
            for line in open(path+"/"+filename):
                if SigData in line:
                    if infected == True:
                        filestodisinfect.append(path+"/"+filename)
    return filestodisinfect
```

I expect this script to find the virus from it's sigdata, which I have done, but need it to print a list of the infected files to an output file.

Comment: `for item in filestodisinfect: print(item)`

Comment: you use `path+"/"+filename` many times in code so you could assign to varaible and use variable `fullpath = path+"/"+filename` - or prefered `fullpath = os.path.join(path, filename))`

Comment: if you want to check all files in subfolders then you could use `os.walk()` which gives files and directories in subfolders too - so you don't have to use recursion.

Comment: Your function returns a list. Just call the function, store the result in a variable, and then iterate through the list in that variable and print (to a file or console).

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

```
mylist=('')
myfile=open('output.txt','w') #Creates file to save list
for item in mylist:
    print >>myfile, item
myfile.close()
```

It created an output txt file, but it won't put the infected files to that file? How can I achieve that from this. Sorry guys I'm new to python and suck.